# Python calendar.month_name How to Skip 0-index

Tags: python, django, calendar

So I am trying to use the Python `calendar` API to loop through the months of the year. Let's say the current month is January (month "1"). If I do `calendar.month_name[1-1]` (A month before January), the result I get is an empty string `""` - seemingly because month "0" doesn't exist. However, if I do `calendar.month_name[1-2]`, the resulting `-1` value leads to `December` being returned.

So my question is how do I get a `month_name[]` parameter of `0` to return the month before it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to store the months in a new variable using a list comprehension

```
months = [month for month in calendar.month_name if month]
```

From here you should be able to see that

```
>>> months[0]
January
>>> months[11]
December
>>> months[-1]
December
```

Edit 1:
As an answer to your comment, you could use the library `itertools`.

```
import calendar
from itertools import cycle
months = [month for month in calendar.month_name if month]

pool = cycle(months[::-1]) # creating a cyclic pool of the reverse list

for month in pool:
    print(month)
```

Output:

```
December
November
October
September
August
July
June
May
April
March
February
January
December
November
October
September
August
July
June
May
April
March
February
January
June
May
April
December
November
October
September
August
July
June
May
April
...
```

Edit 2:

An even easier way could be to recalculate your index, like such

```
import calendar
months = [month for month in calendar.month_name if month]

old_index = -4003

new_index = old_index % len(months)

print(new_index, months[new_index])
```

Output:

```
5 June
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Just one question - how would I get this to work if I want to go back, say 24 months? This method works for up to 12 months, but if I use `-13` I get an `IndexError`

Comment: Just saw your update... wish I could give you even more upvotes. You're the best, thanks!